# jQuery UI date picker displays incorrectly (see-through)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, internet-explorer

I'm having some difficulty with the jQuery date picker control. In my application, I'm using the most basic method to invoke the calendar:

```
$('#elmt').datepicker();
```

The target element is an input text box on a pop-up div. Whenever I click into the textbox, the calendar shows up as see-through: http://s17.postimage.org/4knyxgvjz/see_thru_calendar.png

I've tried some suggestions already on Stackoverflow to adjust the z-index of the ui-datepicker class:

```
.ui-datepicker { width: 17em; padding: .2em .2em 0; display: none; z-index: 9999 !important; }
```

But that hasn't made a difference either. My test environment is running Internet Explorer 7 (the calendar does render OK on the sample index.html provided by jQuery-UI).

Has anyone seen an issue like this with the jQuery UI datepicker?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the UI library?

Comment: @BradBrening Yeah, I'm using 1.8.20. I had the same issues with 1.8.17 as well--have tried both the Cupertino and Redmond themes.

Comment: Can you post the full code of your HTML and CSS files?

Comment: It really looks like a z-index issue.

Comment: Are you also including the custom-theme .css stylesheet for jQuery UI? Without a theme, the datepicker will be see-through.

Comment: Seems like it doesn't load correctly some images or css.

Comment: I can't post the full code, but I could post the CSS of the pop-up and the underlying table.

Comment: @Kevin B I'm including this file: jquery-ui\css\redmond\jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css  -- that is the correct custom theme CSS right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not loading the relevant CSS for the [jQuery UI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/), and that is causing the Calendar to be as "see-through".

**To test it**, edit the CSS file for the jQuery UI and change this `class` `background`:

```
.ui-widget-content {
    background: #000;
}
```

- If the datepicker gets a black background, the style sheet is being
  loaded, but the path for the images might be wrong.
- If no black background, the style sheet isn't being loaded.

---

**Another method** to confirm if the problem lies on the style sheet is to include the CSS directly from the [jQuery CDN](http://code.jquery.com/):

```
http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.20/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css
```

Comment: @ElliotB., added a way for you to check if the style sheet is there or not. Also take note at the images path!

Comment: It didn't turn black and the CSS not loading was indeed the issue. Turns out rel="stylesheet" was missing from the <link> tag: <link type="text/css" href="jquery-ui\css\redmond\jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css"></link>  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: what if it turns black and not coming gray in ie8 only?